# Power query - Source file from Google drive

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop, export-to-excel, google-drive-shared-drive

I have connected csv file from google drive to pwer query as data from Web option. But when data is loaded to query it is showing a document with columns Kind,name,Children and Text instead of data in the csv file.

When i checked the web view it is in the page Google drive can't scan for virus with download anyway option. How to solve this issue and get data from that csv file in google drive (since i need to share this report in excel I can't download csv and give that file path)

Comment: Did you drill into those cells to get the data?